# How do I choose an appropriate fitness function and hyper-parameters to train a 7-DOF arm?

Tags: evolutionary-algorithms, neat, robotics, neuroevolution

I am trying to train an ANN to control a 7 Degrees-Of-Freedom arm. It should reach a target avoiding a single obstacle. Given my modeling of the situation, my input layer is composed of 12 nodes:

- 5 nodes for the 5 joint states
- 3 nodes for the cartesian coordinates of the target
- 3 nodes for the cartesian coordinates of the obstacle
- 1 node for the radius of the obstacle (it's a spherical object).

I have already tried training the ANN with DQN. I want to try neuroevolution (NEAT, in particular) and see how the results compare. I am using [NEAT-python](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). As seen in [this paper](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/dsilva.msreport06.pdf), this should be feasible.

However, I am having trouble choosing the best fitness function and also some other hyperparameters, namely the population size. (I am also puzzled by the extremely long training time for a single generation, but that's another story.)

So, the **fitness function**. I have tried to replicate what I have done with DQN. So, basically, my function evaluates a genome (so, an ANN) as follows (pseudocode):

```
counter = 0
reapeat for NUM_OF_EPISODES times:
    generate a random target
    generate an obstacle which lies about halfway from the end-effector to the target
    repeat for TIMEOUT times:
        use the ANN to decide the next_action and execute it
        if OBSTACLE_REACHED or TARGET_REACHED, stop 
    counter += 0.3 * relative_distance + 0.2 * relative_path + 0.5 * didntHitObstacle()
fitness = counter / NUM_OF_EPISODES
```

So, humanly speaking, for each ANN we try to execute `NUM_OF_EPISODES` times (how many times should be enough? 100 times seems ok but it get's really slow) a scenario. In this scenario, we use the ANN to search for the target, and if we reach it or the obstacle, we stop. Now for each one of these scenarios, we should "rank" how well the ANN performed (see the counter += ... part). But how should I do this? My idea (stolen from the paper above) was to compute something like this:

```
0.3 * relative_distance + 0.2 * relative_path + 0.5 * didntHitObstacle()
```

So, basically, we see how much we are closer to the target compared to when we started, how "short" the path was (compared to the ideal straight line start point-to-target), and whether we did or did not hit the target.

Does this function make sense? My concern is mainly about how we deal with the obstacle: 50% of the fitness. Is it correct? I am asking this because I am receiving poor results.

Another problem that I have is **population size**. Of course, the bigger the better, but this thing takes *a lot* to train. How big is ok, in your experience?

Comment: Do you have a link to a Jupyter notebook?  If you aren't using Python, please don't convert just for me (haha).  Was just looking to take a look at the code.  Glancing at the paper I see that they are using a 6 DOF arm.  Adding another degree of freedom probably exponential increases possibilities, so would be slower to train.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't @JakeJ. If you want I can add the fitness function code in the answer.

Comment: How about a github repo?  Sure, fitness function would help.

Comment: Are you physically running it on the arm for each iteration (I've seen someone who does that)?

Comment: @JakeJ I have no repos right now because this stuff is a "fork" of my main bachelor thesis I have done quickly just to see how it works. Maybe after I will try to add something (the code is a bit messy!).
I am not simulating the arm during training. The arm, in fact, is represented as a chain of segments, and I just have to check with a bit of forward kinematics + linear algebra if the obstacle collides with the segments. Sure, a bit lengthy but the DQN code worked fast enough!

Comment: Cool.  If it takes too long for your liking to train, there are always ways to run it on a GPU (or portions of it).

Comment: @JakeJ for the linear algebra sure, I use numpy so I think that I can easily accelerate that. But for the NEAT itself? I think that depends on how neat-python is written, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what NEAT implementations there are that are GPU enabled, but I should start keeping my eye open.  In the meantime, I saw that you can speed up numpy with a BLAS:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms
I also saw this:  https://github.com/sean-dougherty/accneat (from the catalogue here:  https://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/neat_software/#NEAT ).
That's all the help I can provide as I've not used NEAT or trained neural nets for this application type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92625/discussion-between-nethacker-and-jakej).